# asp.net web application is not working if proxy enabled

Tags: asp.net

my asp application(deployed in local server) is not running if proxy is enabled in a browser, if remove proxy application is working fine, can any one tell me the solultions please...?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have an option for bypassing proxy server for local addresses, so you need to make sure that is checked.  In internet explorer, for example, you can get to this by going to Tools/Internet Options and selecting the connections tab. Then click the Lan Settings button, and there is a checkbox for "Bypass proxy server for local addresses".

By "local server", I assume you mean your own machine.  If that's not the case, then the other thing you can do is click the Advanced button (on the same screen as above) and you can add an exception to the "Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with" section. You can use wildcards here, like *mylocalserver*, for example.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you just need to tell your browser to not use the proxy for local addresses, e.g. localhost.